# Change Stored Procedure List of Parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way to change just the stored procedure call to include more parameters than what the procedure currently has, without affecting the contents of the procedure?

For instance - change from this

```
my_sp param1, param2
```

to this

```
my_sp  param1, paramA, param2, paramB
```

I know this is an odd request and the reason for this is we provide a stored procedure with our program that gets called each time the user submits data through a button click.

As delivered, the stored procedure has no code within it. It is used if the client wants to do some specific updates when the data is submitted. We don't update this stored procedure if it already exists, so as to not wipe out any modifications the client has made to the file.

We now have a requirement to add additional parameters to this stored procedure and need a way to update existing customers' stored procedure without affecting anything they may have added to this stored procedure.

Comment: No, if you don't define the parameters then you must provide *all* of them; you can't provide too many nor too few. This is why you should really be defining the parameter names in the `EXEC` statements. Instead of `EXEC dbo.my_sp Param1, Param2` it should be `EXEc dbo.my_sp @Param1 = 'Param1', @Param2 = 'Param2';`

Comment: Well, *you could* read out the current definition of the stored procedure from within SQL Server into a string, and then use text manipulation to add those extra parameters - but what good would that do? If you can't change the code of the stored procedure, those parameters are never used and never useful .....

Comment: This sounds like a breaking design change. Without knowing the goal for the original procedure, it is difficult and risky for others to comment. You might "wrap" the existing procedure with your new one so that your application code calls the new one which then calls the old one.